# Recording H264 video with Flash player 11 to wowza media server

Tags: apache-flex, h.264, wowza

Currently I'm trying to record H264 video with Flash Player 11 to Wowza 3. 
I am trying to publish the stream using the ‘netstream.publish(“mp4:"+streamId).
When I do that, Wowza creates the file but it is unplayable.

Can anybody please provide help regarding the above issue?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

### Set the correct audio codec

Not sure if this helps - but you have to make sure to not use mp3 as audio-code. Use speex instead:

```
import flash.media.Microphone;
import flash.media.SoundCodec;
```

and

```
microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
```

Answer (score 0):

When U Publish the MP4 File by encoding h264. Which will not play directly in player. u have to post-processed video with a tool called F4V Post Processor. After that, file become playable but there is also some issue that audio is not playing.

So, U have to play directly from your server into your flash player. using `ns.play("mp4:"+FILENAME+".mp4");`  It will play your Video.